# Is it possible to change the default behavior of a command?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

Is it possible to change the default behavior of a command?

I assume that this question is pretty straight forward but let me give an illustration and example.

While connected to some servers via SSH autocomplete via tab does not work making long commands long tedious. For example here is a ls command:

```
ls -lah --group-directories-first
```

This is saying to list all files including hidden files in a top to bottom list in a human readable format while sorting files from directories making directories come first.

Is there a way that I can configure this  `ls` command to perform the above command by simply typing `ls`. By default `ls` list all files. There must be a place where the 'ls' command is located so that when you run it the system knows where to look to find it, see what its default behavior is, and then run it based on the specifications of the provided 'ls' command.

Ultimately can I change the output or default function of the ls command?

Comment: As to your edit, I can see a number of reasons why someone might downvote your question, primarily that it does not show much research effort (that’s actually the tool-tip you get on the downvote button). You’ve also apparently not read the site’s tour or help pages (at least, not since you created your user, hence the “apparently”), although that in itself doesn’t warrant a downvote in my book. Anyway, welcome to Unix.SE!

Comment: Thanks, and I accepted your answer. And I read everything I've been a part of the exchanges for a bit I just thought this was a straight forward question.  But anyway, thanks, and your answer was what I needed.

Comment: You may also be interested in [what's my PATH](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical way of doing this on Unix- or Linux-style systems is to use shell aliases:

```
alias ls='ls -lah --group-directories-first'
```

Note that this will overwrite any existing `ls` alias, so you might want to check the output of

```
alias ls
```

first and combine the above; for example

```
alias ls='ls -lah --group-directories-first --color=tty'
```

To make this permanent, add it to your `.bashrc` file in your home directory (assuming you’re using Bash, which you probably are if you’re discovering all this).

Altering the default behaviour in such an extensive way can end up being confusing, so I’d suggest creating a new command using an alias instead; I have

```
alias l='ls -lah --group-directories-first'
```

for example. This also allows building upon other aliases: this `l` alias uses whatever is defined as `ls`, and if that’s an alias, that gets used to (so there’s no need to repeat the `--color=tty` option in this case).

To remove an alias, use `unalias`:

```
unalias ls
```